# Whitespace between numbers

Tags: php

I would like to set a whitespace between numbers bigger than 999.

So for example:

Not "1000" but "1 000",
Not "10500" but "10 500";

How to do it while formatting a string?

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Have you tried [number_format](http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=EN%2Ffunction.number-format.php&lang=en&scope=404quickref)

Comment: if you are curious as for why people are voting this down (I was not one of them), generally it's expected that you would attempt a little research before posting to SO, and if you are having trouble to post your code example.

Comment: Actually I did research before I posted here but google was throwing useless answers like split_length() or str_repeat().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe looking for the php function [number_format()](http://php.net/number_format)

```
$number= 1000;
if($number > 999){

$number =  number_format($number, 0, '', ' ');
echo $number;

}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/y2OnHZ)

Comment: With answering questions where no effort is shown you're encouraging OP to ask more questions in this quality and this style

Comment: @Rizier123 you're right, I'll pay attention to this in the future, thank you for taking that to my attention.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [number_format()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function.

Example:

```
$a = 1000;
echo number_format($a, 0, '.', ' ');
```

Comment: When posting links please use english one :)

Answer (score 2):

Try with `number_format`, something like this:

```
<?php
  $number = 10500;
  echo number_format($number, 0, '.', ' ');
  // Output 10 500
?>
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: no need to specify the `decimal point` if you're using `0` decimal points, remove the `.`

Comment: @Pedro, you have to specify *something*, because you are setting the 4th parameter, so it makes no difference what you pass as the 3rd.

Comment: you can just use `''` or `null` as argument

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [substr()](http://php.net/substr) function inside of php